# Mesh not deformed correctly and armature not attached to it even if the weight colors are good

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, weight-painting

I'm trying to animate a character with blender 2.71. But before to reach this step I need to fix correctly the armature. The problems is that the mesh is deformed correctly but when I move it the armature seems to be separated from it. Another problem that I have is that even if I have configured correctly the weight colors,the mesh in some regions aren't deformed correctly. You can understand better where are the problems by checking the pictures located here :

[pictures list](http://www.psychonews.it/pics/arm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you parented the bones to wrong objects, here you have the upper legs bone parented to the lower leg mesh.

[image]

It would be way easier to join all the objects to a single one and weight paint againt.