# Why is my armature deforming it's mesh in a wrong way and how can I fix it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature, bones, geometry

[image][image]
I'm trying to get the body to move which I have done, but I notice a part of the body open up or move apart,so how can i fix this or what should I do?
ok why can i do to fix this one in the second picture

Comment: In case you used automatic weighs to link the mesh to armature, you need to adjust the weighs of vertex groups, adding more details, attaching more images and uploading the .blend file, will help you get more accurate answers, you can use this link to upload your file: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mesh not deformed correctly and armature not attached to it even if the weight colors are good](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20913/mesh-not-deformed-correctly-and-armature-not-attached-to-it-even-if-the-weight-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can only be because edges are separated. Try this : go to edit mode, select all vertices and remove doubles. Probably that will fix the problem.

Comment: Ok I will try it

Comment: but out of the direct question, clavicles are inverted.. curious !

Comment: Ok Thank Bro, that help, but what should I fix in this problem now hold on

Comment: I'm not sure about the clavicles are inverted? still getting a little use this

Comment: is that a SL skeleton ?

Comment: well its a skeleton from Radiant Rig Xl. I'm properly worrying, but  is that mash part under his normal or is that something else?